# Newbie CSS positioning/mapping

Tags: css, wordpress, positioning

I'm currently running a word-press theme and I am trying to implement typed.js
I successfully installed and now stuck with the CSS part of it.

As you can see in this screenshot:

[image: scrs]

I am trying to position it properly. But every time I am doing changes on that section, the whole page changes too so i need a solution to make just changes for that part of the typed.js section on the header...

I am a noob in those things but if someone could explain how i can make another section to just edit the typed.js i would really appreciate that.

Comment: use a parent class with the css.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.typed-div-3949 span.typed-preview-div {
   /* Your CSS here like this */
   display: block;
   test-align: center;
}
```

What do you exactly want to achieve? Centered text?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Just want to tweak it.. Centering, size color etc.. Thanks for the help going to try out

Comment: I've tried to add a new rule via google console and its working. But when im trying to add it via the css file it won't do anything... http://prntscr.com/ck727v

Comment: Could be browsercache... Or server-side caching via varnish or somerthin like this. Not easy to say from here :-) consider marking this answer as correct answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change only in one page just add the unique page ID like below

```
#uniqueid .typed-div-3949 span.typed-preview-div {
     /*Add your CSS here */
     text-align: center;
     display: block;
}
```

and yes what do you want to achieve?